# Converting Excel Data into Text File with fixed column position

Tags: excel, text-files

I have an excel file with having a table (Customer Detail) with three columns.

First Column: Name Of the Customer

Second Column : Attention Line of the Customer
Third Column : City, State , Zip of the Customer

The table contains about 100 rows. 
I want to export that table values in a text file. But my problem is that when I copy/paste in the text file or save as a .txt format the column values don't remain in fixed positions. I want the text file with each column values left aligned and first letter or number for each column should remain in fixed position.

Thanks in Advance!

NOTE: I am using Microsoft Excel 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Save As - Formatted Text (Space Delimited) (*.prn). It should detect the width and insert spaces for you